# Questions stay grayed in app after removing tag ignoring on web

Tags: bug, ios-app, ignored-tags

I just added [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag via [profile settings page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/tag-notifications/current) to the ignore list and removed it shortly. On the web related questions look as usual, but on the iOS app they are drawn grayed as if they are staying in the ignore list:

> [image: ignored not ignored]

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: Unknown (iPad7,3)
- OS Version: Version 12.1.4 (Build 16D57)

Comment: Gonna guess that may be cached... is it still an issue?